# Do users with access to DB2 also have access to OS400?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

From what I understand about OS400 and DB2, the two are integrated together. Does that mean they would share the same users at both the operating system and database layers?

If so, is it possible to create users exclusive to 1 layer and not the other? (ie: create a user within DB2 but not OS400)

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. What is it that you _actually_ are trying to accomplish? Typically you define an authorization ID for a purpose; what's your purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one layer, the DB is built into the OS; thus there's only one set of users.

So the short answer to your question is no.

Longer answer, the DB is the OS and the OS is the DB;  but the system has a very robust and capable set of security features & functions.

If you're using the built in web server, there can be a different set of web user IDs and passwords; those users have no direct access to the DB or OS.

What do you hope to accomplish and how will your users be accessing the system?